# Unknown "non-finite double value" Javascript error being thrown

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, action

I ran into the following error while doing actions.moveToElement(ele).click().build().perform() :
javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.

Some searches showed people in Chrome Mobile or other products receiving that, but I am just using the regular ChromeDriver (78) version with Java.  They said it is fixed in a product I am not using.

Has anyone had this in the regular Chrome Driver?

Comment: I have this too from .net core, Ubuntu 18.04, Chrome: 78.0.3904.108, ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105

Answer (score 3):

I found that the cause of me seeing this error was that the element I was trying to click was a `<title>` meta data element. My original code picked an element to click using the visible text on the page:

```cs
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]"));

new Actions(this.Driver)
    .MoveToElement(element, 1, 1)
    .Click()
    .Perform();
```

However, this text also existed in the title of the browser so the returned element was actually a `<title>` metadata element. I haven't created this element, only set `document.title` so somewhat surprised to see it all. I don't think this was past behaviour or was it...?

My fix was to exclude title elements in my xpath query:

```cs
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[not(self::title) and contains(text(), '" + text + "')]"))
```

Note that with the firefox driver, this error surfaces as `rect is undefined`.